# What is the purpose of '&' while passing bool as a function parameter

Tags: programming, c++

If I use this function without `&` before `change_x` (in function parameter), `change_x` never changes to false and it keeps on printing forever. Why do I need `&`?

```
void some_function(bool &change_x, int pin_x) {
 if (change_x == true) {
 delay(time_delay);
 if (digitalRead(pocket_pin_1) == HIGH) {
  Serial.print("State 1");
  }  

 else {
  Serial.println("state 2");
 }
 change_x = false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a boolean b you normally assign it to true or false. If you pass in a function a boolean (or integer, char and most other simple types), a copy is made. So if you change it in the function, when the function returns, the copy is destroyed and the original value is kept.

However, you do not want a copy, so you need a reference (pointer) to that boolean. That is where the & is for. So bool &change is not a boolean, but a reference to a boolean. Whenever you change that reference, the original value of the boolean is changed, which is what you want.

Note, this is a C++ feature, it does not exist in C (there you use pointers instead: bool* change).

Answer (score 1):

As always in C++ the argument is passed by value by default (just like in plain old C). By using '&' you can pass it by reference. Therefore you are not copying the value of the variable into the method but the original variable with the possibility to mutate it inside the function and it will reflect the changes outside the function.

Perhaps you can paste more of your code so we see how the variable is passed into the function. For instance calling `some_function(true, 3)` won't be useful.

But anyway this is not an Arduino specific question and belongs to stackoverflow.